# Dealing with Morris Chart

Tags: javascript, morris.js

so I'm trying to build a line chart using Morris Charts that will display tickets count according to ticket status among the year.

The problem is that I got a little confused about xKey and what goes there.

**Image explaining what i'm trying to do**
[image]

Instead i'm getting two lines, one for status and the other for count

**data**

```
 {period: "2010-09", status: 1, count: 20}
,{period: "2010-10", status: 1, count: 50}
,{period: "2010-10", status: 2, count: 34}
,{period: "2010-11", status: 2, count: 70}
```

**Code**

```
Morris.Area({
            element: 'morris-area-chart'
            , data: data
            , xkey: 'period'
            , ykeys:  ['count','status']
            , labels: ['processing', 'done']
});
```

I know I'm messing something up but i can't find out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your data like that:

```
 {period: "2010-09", status1Count: 20, status2Count: 12}
,{period: "2010-10", status1Count: 50, status2Count: 34}
,{period: "2010-11", status1Count: 70, status2Count: 25}
```

and chart codes:

```
Morris.Area({
            element: 'morris-area-chart'
            , data: data
            , xkey: 'period'
            , ykeys:  ['status1Count','status2Count']
            , labels: ['processing', 'done']
});
```